# JS: Find a collection of items which have a specific value in one of their array properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How to find with the most efficient way (via Underscore or pure JS) a collection of items which have a specific value in one of their array properties?

E.g.:

```
var collection = [
    {
        name: 'item 1',
        tags: [
            'tag-1',
            'tag-2',
            'tag-3'
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'item 2',
        tags: [
            'tag-2',
            'tag-4',
            'tag-5'
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'item 3',
        tags: [
            'tag-1',
            'tag-3',
            'tag-4'
        ]
    }
];
```

I would like to get all the items which have `tags-3` in their `tags` property.

So I'll expect to get:

```
{
    name: 'item 1',
    tags: [
        'tag-1',
        'tag-2',
        'tag-3'
    ]
},
{
    name: 'item 3',
    tags: [
        'tag-1',
        'tag-3',
        'tag-4'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter it using Underscore's [`filter` function](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var results = _.filter(collection, function(item) {
    return item.tags.indexOf("tag-3") !== -1;
});
```

There's also ES5's [`Array#filter`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20) (which needs a shim on older browsers):

```
var results = collection.filter(function(item) {
    return item.tags.indexOf("tag-3") !== -1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using it in node, so I'll go with the native filter() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the collection with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var collection = [{
    name: 'item 1',
    tags: [
        'tag-1',
        'tag-2',
        'tag-3'
    ]
}, {
    name: 'item 2',
    tags: [
        'tag-2',
        'tag-4',
        'tag-5'
    ]
}, {
    name: 'item 3',
    tags: [
        'tag-1',
        'tag-3',
        'tag-4'
    ]
}]

var results = collection.filter(function (item) {
    return item.tags.indexOf('tag-3') !== -1;
});
```

However, since this method is not yet supported by all browsers, you can try this code:

```
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if (collection[i].tags.indexOf('tag-3') !== -1) {
        results.push(collection[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `return item.tags.indexOf('tag-3') !== -1 ? item : false;` should be `return item.tags.indexOf('tag-3') !== -1;` You just return true/false for `filter`, not the item (you're sort of combining `filter` and `map`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the filter() method is a very elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible (has-been) solution :

```
function findAll(array, fn) {
    var i = -1, result = [];
    while (++i < array.length) {
        if (fn(array[i]) === true) {
            result.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function has(value, array) {
    var i = -1;
    while (++i < array.length) {
        if (array[i] === value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage example :

```
var a = [
    { a: [1, 2, 3] }, 
    { a: [3, 4, 5] }, 
    { a: [5, 6, 7] }
];
var result = findAll(a, function (item) {
    return has(5, item.a);
});
result; // [{ a: [3, 4, 5] }, { a: [5, 6, 7] }]
```